# Pig Script Error: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: apache-pig

I run the following code snippet for Pig:

```
publisher_hour_listings_cdf = foreach rscf_pub_hours_cumsum_proj generate
            rscf_publisher_id,
            rscf_is_uw,
            rscf_hour,
            (int)rscf_hour as rscf_hour_int,
            rscf_cum_listings,
            total_daily_listings,
            (rscf_cum_listings*1.0)/(total_daily_listings*1.0) as cdf,
            '$handledDate$';
```

and I get an error:

> 2020-05-02 04:31:53,130 INFO - [Step] - thread 74038 -
>   /opt/pig/pig-0.17.0/bin/pig: [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:
>   Exception while executing (Name: publisher_hour_listings_cdf: New For
>   Each(false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-203
>   Operator Key: scope-203):
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:
>   Exception while executing [POCast (Name: Cast[long] - scope-171
>   Operator Key: scope-171) children: [[POProject (Name: Project[int][3]
>   - scope-170 Operator Key: scope-170) children: null at []]] at [rscf_cum_listings[-1,-1]]]: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   **java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**

We thought that Pig fails to cast Long to Integer. 
We tried to cast with "biginteger" instead of "int":

```
        (biginteger)rscf_hour as rscf_hour_int
```

and the script also failed with the exact same error message.

We also tried to remove the int casting at all:

```
    rscf_hour as rscf_hour_int
```

and we still got the same error.

Do you know why?